# CloudantDB: RestAPI with specific parameter

Tags: java, angularjs, mongodb, cloudant

I just created new doc on Cloudant dashboard

```
{
  "_id": "548de788223ed6fa9f1dd6db1b51a32e",
  "_rev": "9-364c9192decc39941cae864819a80cba",
  "username": "admin",
  "password": "admin"
}
```

, and get API url: https://xxx.cloudant.com/demo/548de788223ed6fa9f1dd6db1b51a32e.

Can we put `username` to url instead of `_id`? I want to put exactly that field and not the default `_id`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the id field to any value you like when creating a document.  If using the cloudant dashboard, then when you create a record and add the JSON, you can edit the id it has autogenerated for you.

When creating records programmatically, make a PUT request to the URL you want to use rather than a POST to the database that you're adding the document to.  Either approach will set the URL to your desired format with the username rather than the unique identifier.

Comment: Thanks Lorna, as you say we only use url instead put the parameter. But I want to use cloudantDB to create login function. if i have 200 account, we need to manual create on dashboard. Be cause the _id has auto generated, we cannot auto change it, is it right ?